# SpringBoot 2.6.2 and form data

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, post, request-mapping

I am experimenting with a controller endpoint that looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("login")
fun login(
    @RequestParam username: String,
    @RequestParam password: String): ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> {
    // ...
}
```

The request is send from a HTML form looking like this:

```
<form action="../api/login" method="POST">
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required=""><br>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required=""><br>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

This works perfectly will with spring boot version 2.6.1. But after an upgrade to version 2.6.2 and adding spring cloud gateway it all of a sudden does not work any longer.
The log would look like this:

```
2022-01-11 14:33:09,618 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod - [3d97dc1a-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:13027] Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.example.models.LoginResponse> com.example.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): 400 BAD_REQUEST "Required String parameter 'username' is not present"
2022-01-11 14:33:09,656 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.HttpLogging - [3d97dc1a-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:13027] Resolved [ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Required String parameter 'username' is not present"] for HTTP POST /api/login
```

I tried various things like:

```
@PostMapping(value = ["login"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
fun login(
        @RequestParam  paramMap: MultiValueMap<String,String>
      ): ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> {
    //...
}
```

But also this fails with the following log:

```
2022-01-11 14:10:11,589 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [656327b1-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:11772] HTTP POST "/api/login"
2022-01-11 14:10:11,601 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG o.s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - [656327b1-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:11772] Mapped to com.example.ApiController#login(MultiValueMap)
2022-01-11 14:10:12,945 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG o.s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestBodyMethodArgumentResolver - Form data is accessed via ServerWebExchange.getFormData() in WebFlux.
2022-01-11 14:10:21,640 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod - [656327b1-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:11772] Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.example.models.LoginResponse> com.example.ApiController.login(org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>): 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
```

I would guess the error message with `415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE` is just misleading and it somehow fails to map the form-data. What can I do to get the API again accept form-data?

Trying something like:

```
@PostMapping(value = ["login"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
    fun login(@RequestParam paramMap: Map<String,String>): ResponseEntity<LoginCodeResponse> {
   // ...
}
```

Actually get's called but paramMap is always empty.

What actually works is the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
class HelloWorldController(){

    @GetMapping("hello")
    fun helloName(@RequestParam name: String): String {
        return "Hello $name!"
    }
}
```

So for a normal get request `@RequestParam` works as expected.

**Update**

I seems to boil down to the following. With *spring-boot-starter-webflux* it seems the `@RequestParam` for form-data does not work. This seem to be [a known issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20738).

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
```

With *spring-boot-starter-web* it  `@RequestParam` for form-data works.

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

But this starter is not compatible with spring cloud. Using both    *spring-boot-starter-web* with setting `spring.main.web-application-type=reactive` makes spring cloud gateway start with *spring-boot-starter-web* but still `@RequestParam` for form-data not working.

Comment: You added spring-cloud and i suspect something is misconfigured as it isn't passing along the the request parameters. So trying to fix this at the controller level isn't the solution, you need to fix the cloud configuration.

Comment: I made a test with `@RequestParam` in a normal GET request and there it works as expected. So far I had no success trying to identify a configuration that has an effect on `@RequestParam`. I have not applied any configuration for spring cloud, there is just a spring cloud gateway that proxies a given route.

Comment: Now the fact that you use webflux and not plain web is a piece of crucial information you actually left out. As stated by that issue it will only work for web and not webflux. When using webflux I suggest to use the more functional approach and use  the `ServerRequest` to non-blocking get the params in the code instead of using the annotations. That will work.

Comment: After a manual update did not work I used spring initializr to get a new build.gradle.kts. I realized only now that I had webflux instead of web now. And In my previous searches about form-data with post not working with spring cloud I did not find the issue. But now I found it an now I know. Will extract the values manually from the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from data with POST working with webflux I did the following using  the nicely provided [awaitFormData](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/kdoc-api/spring-webflux/org.springframework.web.reactive.server/await-form-data.html) method:

```
@PostMapping("authorize", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
suspend fun login(exchange: ServerWebExchange): ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> {

    val formData = exchange.awaitFormData()

    val username = formData["username"]?.get(0)!!
    val password = formData["password"]?.get(0)!!
```

That is just a sketch of the essentials of the solution. If you want to use this you should also add some proper error handling to check whether parameters are there otherwise you will just have an error 500 which does not tell a lot.